# Android: update system app

Tags: android, adb

I'm updating my system app using:

```
adb install -r app.apk
```

And this works. If instead I type:

```
adb shell
pm install -r app.apk
```

(the apk push into the device is omitted) it returns:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]

Any idea of the reason why? The adb command what actually does in the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that you need to upload the file into the temp directory (no idea of the reason why).

Like this:

```
adb push app.apk /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

Then procede as normal:

```
adb shell pm install -r /data/local/tmp/app.apk
```

And everything works just normal.

Comment: i get the following error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]

Comment: maybe you are problems with permissions. Like you are running it as root (or you are not root).

Comment: Wouldn't it install the updates into /data/app/ directory?